# How to get a bit from a integer using GLSL and OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I have an integer value and want to get the Bit which is placed on a special location. I'm working with GLSL for OpenGL ES 2.0

Something like this:

```
GetBitOnLocation(int value, int location)
{
  bit myBit = value[location];
  if (myBit == 0)
    return 0;
  if (myBit == 1)
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: In general you don't want to do this; GPUs tend to be weak at integer bit mangling, and forcing the GPU to do this for millions of fragments, or tens of thousands of vertices is normally a bad idea from a performance point of view.

Answer (score 2):

As per the previous comments, don't do this.

ES 2 hardware needn't natively support integers; it is permitted to emulate them as floating point. To permit that, direct bit tests aren't defined.

If you're absolutely desperate, use a `mod` and a `step`. E.g. to test the third bit of the integer `value`:

```
float bit = step(0.5, mod(float(value) / 8.0, 1.0));
// bit is now 1.0 if the lowest bit was set, 0.0 otherwise
```

The logic being to shuffle the bit you want to test into the `0.5` position then cut off all bits above it with the `mod`. Then the value you have can be greater than or equal to `0.5` only if the bit you wanted was set.

Comment: if you want another bit than the third change 8.0 to 2^position. e.g: 2^4=16.0 for the fourth bit ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using integer math (note: negative integers not supported)

```
// 2^x
int pow2(int x){
    int res = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<=31;i++){
        if (i<x){
            res *= 2;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

// a % n
int imod(int a, int n){
    return a - (n * (a/n));
}

// return true if the bit at index bit is set
bool bitInt(int value, int bit){
    int bitShifts = pow2(bit);
    int bitShiftetValue = value / bitShifts;
    return imod(bitShiftetValue, 2) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int GetBitOnLocation(int value, int location)
{
    int myBit = value & (1 << location);
    if (myBit == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this worked, for all I know GLSL ES(at least the version used for OpenGL ES 2.0) does not support bitwise operators.

Comment: GLSL ES 2.0 does not allow bitwise operators.